# Set activity content according to current time android

Tags: android, datetime

I am working on a daily devotional app but I need to get the right information on a problem.
I made the app offline where I set each day with a corresponding content. However, I want to correctly show set content for a day automatically when the user opens the app.
For example, if today was 21st of January, and the user opens the app it should immediately show contents for that day. How do I implement this. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: `I set each day with a corresponding content` --> How do you have done it. For each day of 365 days, Do you have different content?

Comment: Yes. I do have different content for each

Comment: Any other idea would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to maintain DataBase (in SQL lite or [ROOM](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) (android)) so put your data into your database then whenever you needed just you need to call query to fetch data and show your content accordingly.

Follow step :-

1. Need to create DB and make your table related to content.
2. Put your data according to your requirement (means how you want to show on your content into your app)
3. Last when ever you open your app then you need to fire query from data base according to your date.
4. After fetching data from your query you just need to put data into your UI.

[Room in android.](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html)

[SQL in android](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

From where ever you are fetching content just pass the current date and get the data with respect to that date. If you are fetching content from local db you could use a simple sql query like :

`"select * from content where date = " +  date + " ;"`;

Comment: So you mean I have to use SQL database to store my data first

Comment: Storage could be anything. If it is sql above is solution. It could be firebase as well or key value pair like `sharedPref`. I would recommend `sql` since you would be able to structure your data well.